# Import library into xamarin

Tags: xamarin, nuget, xamarin-studio

How do you import a library into Xamarin?

For instance, how would i import [json.net](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json) into xamarin for my project?

Thanks

Comment: Right Click on project and select add refrence if you want to add a library or .dll. You can find online also by selecting nuget.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Json.NET](http://components.xamarin.com/view/json.net) is available as a nicely packaged free [Xamarin-compatible Component](http://components.xamarin.com/view/json.net) from the [Component Store](http://components.xamarin.com).  You can also install from NuGet, but it is generally more difficult to determine which NuGet packages are Xamarin (or PCL) compatible.

Comment: Ok, but what about libraries that are not in the component store? Personal libraries? For future reference.

Comment: if they are Xamarin compatible, just add the DLL to References, or include the source project in your solution and add the project to References.  It's the same as any .NET project

Answer (score 2):

Go to
Project=>Add Packages..
Should see Json.NET, just check it.

Answer (score 1):

What's your IDE?

if Xamarin Studio:
   (your project root node) => Add Packages..., then type in the search box.

if Visual Studio:
   right click on References of your project, and click Manage NuGet Packages..., then type in the search box.

Answer (score 0):

In xamarin studio Go to Project  -> Add Packages 
Search Json.NE and added.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Adding packages is really easy. Just click the settings cog on the Xamarin Packages folder in the solution explorer to add packages.

Also I am not sure why your question was downvoted. Seems like a good one to me (Upvoted)!

Answer (score 0):

Go to solution window and check your project.

Right click on component->click on "get more component" -> search for required package and Click on "Add"

thus, you can get your required package.